# Ivy cachepath fails on any dependency

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I try to include jacoco coverage tool in my ant/ivy build.

I have added the following line to my build.xml

```
<ivy:cachepath organisation="org.jacoco" module="org.jacoco.ant" revision="0.7.5.201505241946" inline="true" conf="test" pathid="jacoco.classpath"/>
<taskdef resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="jacoco.classpath"/>
```

as far as I understood this resolves the jacoco ant jar and allows me to define my task.

Running this fails though with

```
[ivy:cachepath] WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:cachepath] WARN:   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:cachepath] WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:cachepath] WARN:   :: org.jacoco#org.jacoco.ant;0.7.5.201505241946: configuration not public in org.jacoco#org.jacoco.ant;0.7.5.201505241946: 'test'. It was required from org.jacoco#org.jacoco.ant-caller;working test
[ivy:cachepath] WARN:   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:cachepath]     report for org.jacoco#org.jacoco.ant-caller;working test produced in /home/vagrant/.ant/cache/org.jacoco-org.jacoco.ant-caller-test.xml
[ivy:cachepath]     resolve done (2431ms resolve - 0ms download)
```

It complains something about 'ant-caller', but this is something I cannot find anywhere.

Do I miss something or how can I get jacoco ant resolved to be able to define the task ?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I tried it also for other libraries (cobertura, google guava) and for all libraries, e.g. for guava

```
[ivy:cachepath] :: resolving dependencies :: com.google.guava#guava-caller;working
[ivycachepath]  confs: [test]
[ivy:cachepath]     found com.google.guava#guava;18.0 in public
[ivy:cachepath] :: resolution report :: resolve 2138ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|       test       |   1   |   1   |   1   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
[ivy:cachepath] 
[ivy:cachepath] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:cachepath] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:cachepath]         ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:cachepath]         ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:cachepath]         ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:cachepath]         :: com.google.guava#guava;18.0: configuration not public in com.google.guava#guava;18.0: 'test'. It was required from com.google.guava#guava-caller;working test
[ivy:cachepath]         ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:cachepath] 
[ivy:cachepath] :: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `conf="test"` in `<ivy:cachepath>`?

Comment: the purpose was to define it to be part of the test configuration. But removing it actually helped - the dependency could be downloaded and I could proceed.